# Omnet++ : How to use iperf tool at omnetpp?

Tags: omnet++, iperf, iperf3

I want sent UDP packet for 10 seconds from host to server.
Then after 10 seconds I want to calculate how many packages are dropped.
By professor suggest iperf tool. He is not sure though if it is possible to use iperf tool with omnetpp.

My question is it possible to use iperf tool with omnetpp?
If yes, then how can I use that with omnetpp at my topology.
else if no, then how can I achieve that at omnetpp.

Answer (score 0):

While technically it is possible to use an external app to drive traffic in INET, it might be quite complicated. Sending UDP packet bursts (or a single burst) is absolutely possible with native INET apps, for example with [UdpBasicApp](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/applications/udpapp/UdpBasicApp.ned#L50). You have `startTime` and `stopTime`, `sendInterval` and `messageLength` at your disposal.

Comment: I want to count packet drops.